# Missing commands on Alexa Skills Kit CLI

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework, ask-cli

I’ve just upgraded from `jovo-cli` `1.0.13` to `1.2.10` and now am experiencing issues with `ask-cli`. I’m not sure why these would be connected but I used to be able to run `jovo deploy -p alexaSkill` without issue, now when I run it it throws the following error:

```
❯ Deploying Alexa Skill (stage: dev)
  ✖ Creating Alexa Skill project for ASK profile default
    -> error: ask-api(1) does not exist, try --help
```

I have tried updating `ask-cli` to version `1.4.9` and fully deleting, reinstalling and re-initializing. Neither of which worked.

Weirdly of the all the available `ask` commands, `init`, `deploy`, `new`, `clone`, `simulate`, `validate`, `diff`, `dialog`, and `help` are all present and can be invoked. It’s specifically all the list commands that are throwing this error (`lambda`, `api`, `add`, `remove`, and `util`).

Has anyone encountered this before? What other steps can I take to try and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received a solution on the Jovo Slack Community.

The cause of this issue was installation of the `ask-cli` using `yarn`. Uninstalling then reinstalling via `npm` and re-initializing solved the issue immediately.